# Start a java-program from the browser

Tags: java, html, servlets

so for my university i have written a program that simulates a small and exemplary telephonebook. With the program you can search for numbers or names or both and it will spit out the results.
The input runs over a small gui(JFrame with textfields) and the output is via console.

Now the next task is to have a server (originaly on another computer, but now that is supposed to be on the same) that is the telephone-book program. And the user calls the server via browser to give the server the number or name and gets the result back.

Now i dont know how to do this.
I googled around a little and found that i should use a Servlet.
Is that correct? If so, I could use some help with that.

With my understanding I write another class that extends from HttpServlet and from there i call my methods?! But how do i then call onClickListener etc which i will need.

EDIT: We are supposed to use Server Sockets explicitely.

I hope i was more or less clear.
Any help appreciated=)
Greetings

Comment: You need a basic tutorial in HTTP and HTML first, I think. It's a fundamentally different model.

Comment: Html i know basics and maybe a bit more, same goes for javascript=)

Comment: JAVA servlet plugin in browser is a very old way to meet your need.Html and javascript web app is the most popular way to develop a browser based GUI.And http based web service or ajax call is popular way to make your client GUI to communicate with your JAVA server.

Answer (score 1):

Many ways to do as everyone else mentioned and but if you don't want to change your Swings code then try with java web start. Read basic tutorial [here](http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-web-start-jnlp-tutorial-unofficial-guide/)

Comment: the swing code can (and should be , says professor) thrown away. he is rater(very) old and does things the oldfashioned way. We are supposed to use server sockets

Comment: how is this you want to achieve in a web page I assume? "And the user calls the server via browser to give the server the number or name and gets the result back." If so then you need to convert your app to webapp with JSP/Servlet. Try to break the code into layers and write basic jsp for request/response. You need to read about web application development - Check out https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gkanq.html or http://www.zeepedia.com/read.php?java_addressbook_case_study_using_sevlets_web_design_and_development&b=20&c=33

Comment: yes via a webpage the user puts in data(names or numbers) which is then used in the server(my program). I will look into your link, thanks=)

Answer (score 0):

To put it in simple words,
Create a web service that takes search query and returns the result in response.
On onClickListener event, call the web service and handle the response to display on your GUI.

Comment: I think there is some misunderstanding either on my or your side=) Or i dont understand it fully what you mean. 
The program i wrote earlier is supposed to be the server and handles the results, not the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm out of touch with the modern Servlet framework, but last time I looked, there is no `onClickListener`. Unless you mean something like Javascript within a HTML page, or something within GWT or similar framework.

Maybe what you need is a "windowing" framework which emulates your existing knowledge of client-side Java, such as [Echo Web Framework](http://echo.nextapp.com/site) ?

Disclaimer: I have not examined this framework in over 5 years, as I was never familiar with the client-side approach.

[Demo here](http://demo.nextapp.com/Demo/app)

Answer (score 0):

To clear things up.
Our Professor gave us a functioning Server class. And a Html that works in conjunction. So the main problem was cleared when I found these.

Thanks anyway folks=)